# AngularJS Controller $scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have a controller für each site in my angularJS application. 
In this case I have one site with the form for creating a user and if form is submitted, user is navigated to a success- page which summarizes user creation and provides info about created user.

At the bottom there are the two controllers. My approach is that after server response I set username, passwords and roles in $rootScope. Then I navigate to "usercreateresponse" page and afterwards I view this properties with {{username}}, {{password}} and {{roles}}.

This works so far but I have one problem with this approach: if I reload the page "usercreateresponse" then the values of username, password and roles disapprear, actually I don't know why, because I have set the values in rootscope (so I believe that the rootScope maybe is cleaned up by refreshing?!)

My question now would be, if my approach is ok or is there a better solution (e.g. to transfer values over parameter?, only one controller for user handling?).
Thanks a lot!

```
function CreateUserController($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope,  $cookieStore) {    
$scope.createUser = function(data) {
    var dataObj = {
            username : $scope.username,
            password : $scope.password,
            roles: [$scope.role]
    };  
    var res = $http.post('/users/createUser', dataObj);
    res.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $rootScope.username = data.username;
        $rootScope.password = data.password;
        $rootScope.role = data.roles;
        $rootScope.id = data.id;

        $location.path("usercreateresponse");
    });
    res.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert( "failure message: " + JSON.stringify({data: data}));
    });     
   }
 }
```

Controller for sucessfully user creation:

```
function CreateUserResponseController($scope) {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use $emit or $broadcast to transfer data object that contains username, password, etc by

```
$scope.$emit('userCreated', data);
```

in CreateUserController success and listen to this by,

```
$scope.$on('userCreated', function(newVal, oldVal) {

$scope.userName = newVal.userName;
 ....
});
```

in usercreateresponse(CreateUserResponseController)

Comment: Many thanks for the answer. I thought that $emit should be used rarely - therefore I havn't used this approach. Thanks!